# call worksheet event change when user doesn't deselect cell

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet-function

I have a very simple `Worksheet_Change` event running so that if any cell on the worksheet changes a cell on another sheet changes to 1.  I am using that cell as a flag to know if any changes have been made to the worksheet.  I have a shape that I assigned a macro to when selected.  The macro checks to see if any changes have been made (if that cell is set to 1), and if it is my code fires.

The problem is if for example

- cell `A1` contains the name Bob.
- A user selects cell `A1` and changes the name from Bob to Steve
- but then instead of first clicking out of the cell and then clicking the shape they directly hit the shape without deselecting the cell.

The problem with this is that the `worksheet_change` event doesn't trigger until after my macro completes.  So while the macro runs the flag is set to 0, but once it's done the flag gets set to 1.

Any ideas on how to stop this?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    sheets("Cond For").Range("A1").Value = 1
End Sub

Sub saveData()

if sheets("Cond For").Range("A1").Value = 1 Then
    'my code
End if

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use two routines like so (rename Sheet1.Reallysave to your sheet's codename and routine name):

```
Sub SaveData()
Application.Ontime Now, "Sheet1.ReallySave"
End Sub

Sub ReallySave()
'Your current code
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! I never heard of the OnTime function before.